# Creating my own connected chart table JavaFx

Tags: user-interface, javafx, charts, components

So after nearly two weeks of trying to find a solution to my problem I have now decided that I want to make my own `JavaFX` component.

The idea is to create a table that is connected with the already existing charts such as line chart and bar chart.

Since I am fairly new to `JavaFX` (I've been going on for about 1 month or so) I have a few questions before I start on a project like this:

First and foremost can it be done? Before answering that I would like to show you an example of what my goal is:

[image]

This picture is taken from the Java plug-in `JFreeChart` and has a connected table on the x-Axis.

My goal isn't necessarily that the chart and table must be 100% connected as shown in the picture however it is of very importance that there under each point/bar etc. is a connected table with data information.

An example of a bar chart with a connected table would be the following picture:

[image]

Since I already have the chart (the build in charts in `JavaFX`) how hard of a job do you guys recon that this will be? Also is it even possible?

I am also very interested to hear if you guys have any suggestions on how to create this component or suggestions on how to actually create a component.

Comment: You have 3 other questions that ask the exact same thing. Please think about consolidating them into a single question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is is an example solution, explosives are up, ducks are down.

[image: linechartwithtable]

```
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337062/creating-my-own-connected-chart-table-javafx
public class TabulatedLineChartWithLegend extends Application {
  private final static String MONTHS[] = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
    
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Line Chart With Attached Tabulated Data");

    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    xAxis.setTickLength(0);
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

    final LineChart<String, Number> lineChart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);
    lineChart.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0;");
    lineChart.setLegendVisible(false);
    lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");
    lineChart.getData().addAll(createSeries("ACME Explosives"), createSeries("DUCK Rubber Ducks"));
 
    VBox vbox = new VBox(5);
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(lineChart, createTableView(lineChart));
    vbox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
    vbox.setMinWidth(500);
    VBox.setMargin(lineChart, new Insets(0,0,0,114));
    
    HBox layout = new HBox();
    layout.getChildren().add(vbox);
    HBox.setHgrow(vbox, Priority.ALWAYS);
    
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 700, 500);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }
  
  private Series createSeries(String name) {
    XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
    series.setName(name);
    final ObservableList data = series.getData();
    final DataGenerator generator = new DataGenerator();
    for (String month: MONTHS) {
      data.add(generator.createDataItem(month));
    }
    
    return series;
  }
  
  private TableView createTableView(final LineChart<String, Number> chart) {
    TableView<XYChart.Series<String,Number>> table = new TableView();
    
    if (!chart.getData().isEmpty()) {
      TableColumn legendCol = new TableColumn("Legend");
      legendCol.setResizable(false);
      legendCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new Callback<CellDataFeatures<XYChart.Series<String,Number>, String>, ObservableValue<XYChart.Series<String,Number>>>() {
          @Override public ObservableValue<Series<String, Number>> call(CellDataFeatures<Series<String, Number>, String> param) {
            return new SimpleObjectProperty(param.getValue());
          }
        }  
      );
      legendCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<XYChart.Series<String,Number>,Series<String, Number>>,TableCell<XYChart.Series<String,Number>,Series<String, Number>>>() {
        @Override public TableCell<Series<String, Number>, Series<String, Number>> call(TableColumn<Series<String, Number>, Series<String, Number>> param) {
          return new TableCell<Series<String, Number>, Series<String, Number>>() {
            @Override protected void updateItem(Series<String, Number> series, boolean empty) {
              super.updateItem(series, empty);
              if (series != null) {
                setText(series.getName());
                setGraphic(createSymbol(series, chart.getData().indexOf(series)));
              }  
            }
          };
        }
      });
      table.getColumns().add(legendCol);

      final ObservableList<Data<String, Number>> firstSeriesData = chart.getData().get(0).getData();
      for (final Data<String, Number> item: firstSeriesData) {
        TableColumn col = new TableColumn(item.getXValue());
        col.setSortable(false);
        col.setResizable(false);
        col.prefWidthProperty().bind(chart.getXAxis().widthProperty().divide(firstSeriesData.size()));
        col.setCellValueFactory(
          new Callback<CellDataFeatures<XYChart.Series<String,Number>, String>, ObservableValue<Number>>() {
            @Override public ObservableValue<Number> call(CellDataFeatures<XYChart.Series<String,Number>, String> param) {
              for (Data<String, Number> curItem: param.getValue().getData()) {
                if (curItem.getXValue().equals(item.getXValue())) {
                  return curItem.YValueProperty();
                }
              }
              
              return null;
            }
          }  
        );
        table.getColumns().add(col);
      }
      
      for (XYChart.Series<String,Number> series: chart.getData()) {
        table.getItems().add(series);
      }  

      table.setEditable(false);
      table.setFocusTraversable(false);
    }  
    
    table.setTranslateY(-30);
    table.setPrefHeight(88);
    table.setStyle("-fx-box-border: transparent; -fx-focus-color: transparent; -fx-padding: 0 9 0 9;");
    
    return table;
  }
  
  private Node createSymbol(Series<String, Number> series, int seriesIndex) {
    Node symbol = new StackPane();
    symbol.getStyleClass().setAll(
      "chart-line-symbol", 
      "series" + seriesIndex,
      "default-color" + (seriesIndex % 8)
    );
    return symbol;
  }  
 
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}

// generates random chart data.
class DataGenerator {
  private static final Random random = new Random();
  private int delta = 0;
  private int trend = random.nextInt(4) - 1;
  public Data createDataItem(String month) {
    return new XYChart.Data(month, genDataVal());
  }
  private int genDataVal() {
    delta += trend;
    return random.nextInt(20) + 15 + delta;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you explain the part where you actually group them together with the following code:

  legendCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new Callback<CellDataFeatures<XYChart.Series<String,Number>, String>, ObservableValue<XYChart.Series<String,Number>>>() {
     public ObservableValue<Series<String, Number>> call(CellDataFeatures<Series<String, Number>, String> param) {
            return new SimpleObjectProperty(param.getValue());
          }
        }
      );

Comment: That code says that the value of the each cell in the legend is the corresponding chart series represented by the table row for that cell.